# Putting out on every hole in a bogey competition

Tags: rules, golf

Do you have to putt out on every hole in a bogey competition even when you are over par on a hole ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is played on a hole-by-hole basis so once you have lost the hole you can pick up. The rules even encourage you to pick up when you are out of a hole.

[From the R&A Rules 21.3b](https://www.randa.org/en/rog/2019/rules/the-rules-of-golf/rule-21#21-3b)

**Scoring in Par/Bogey**

If the player’s score is higher than the fixed score, or no score is returned, the player loses the hole.

A player who does not hole out under the Rules for any reason loses the hole.

*To help pace of play, players are encouraged to stop playing a hole when their score exceeds the fixed score (as they have lost the hole).*